# Is the Harry Potter government democratic?

Tags: harry-potter, government

I recently [came across](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/is-a-squib-a-muggle/14530#comment499198_14530) the article [Harry Potter and the Half-Crazed Bureaucracy](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=830765), an interesting analysis of Rowling's dark portrayal of government in the *Harry Potter* series. One of the first claims it makes is that the Potterverse government has no elections and no democracy.

Thinking about it, I don't recall any mention of elections in the series. Over a seven-year period in the Muggle UK, there should have been at least one general election, but the only changes of leader during this period in the magical UK are when a weak and discredited Minister resigns and when a psycho murderer takes over the government and kills the incumbent Minister.

**How does a magical government take power?** Are there elections which we just don't see (perhaps because the main characters are too young to vote)? Is the Ministry of Magic associated with a Muggle government like other ministries? Are there different political parties in the magical world?

<sub>Canon evidence only, please. I'll reluctantly accept evidence from the films, but no fanfic or unsourced Wikia claims.</sub>

Comment: not entirely but something related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149108/what-forms-of-government-are-there-in-the-harry-potter-series

Comment: The answer about UK elections for the Minister of Magic and why we do not see the in the books is here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149108/what-forms-of-government-are-there-in-the-harry-potter-series