# Is it possible to change the magical government?

Tags: harry-potter

Is it possible to change the Ministry without enraging the "pure blood" families? Even more, is it even possible to change the world views of the families themselves?

Comment: Change the Ministry how? In terms of policies? Their system of government

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["How is the Minister for Magic chosen and what qualifications are required to hold office?"](https://www.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15205/how-is-the-minister-for-magic-chosen-and-what-qualifications-are-required-to-hol)

Comment: @TheDarkLord that link should be https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15205/how-is-the-minister-for-magic-chosen-and-what-qualifications-are-required-to-hol - giving me a certificate error (there's a `www` in front of the `scifi`)

Answer (score 8):

## JKR said in an interview that the Ministry of Magic *did* change.

In a live chat on Bloomsbury after the series was done, JKR said that Kingsley Shacklebolt and Hermione Granger worked to remove all the “pro-pure-blood” laws.

> Does hermione still continue to do work with SPEW and is life any better for house elves!
>
> J.K. Rowling: Hermione began her post-Hogwarts career at the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures where she was instrumental in greatly improving life for house-elves and their ilk. She then moved (despite her jibe to Scrimgeour) to the Dept. of Magical Law Enforcement where she was a progressive voice who ensured the eradication of oppressive, pro-pureblood laws. 
> <sub><sup>*[Bloomsbury Live Chat (2007)](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript/)*</sup></sub>

So according to that, the Ministry was indeed changed. The change likely did enraged whatever pure-bloods who believed that pure-bloods were superior were left, but since there weren’t many of them and they’d have less of an influence on the government, it wouldn’t matter that much.

### It’s unlikely the pure bloods will change their minds but they’re dying off.

There weren’t that many pure-bloods left that believed in favoring those of purer blood status. The wizards who were technically pure-bloods but didn’t care about blood status wouldn’t be bothered by the Ministry removing laws favoring pure-bloods. There were already very few pure-bloods even before the war (even counting ones like the Weasleys who didn’t care about blood status). After the war was over, there would be even less of the pure-bloods who were in favor of these laws, since most of the Death Eaters would have either died in the war or been thrown into Azkaban.

> “The pure-blood families are all interrelated,’ said Sirius. ‘If you’re only going to let your sons and daughters marry pure-bloods your choice is very limited; there are hardly any of us left. Molly and I are cousins by marriage and Arthur’s something like my second cousin once removed. But there’s no point looking for them on here – if ever a family was a bunch of blood traitors it’s the Weasleys.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 6 (The Noble and Most Ancient House of Black)*</sup></sub>

Those that remained would likely have to hide their beliefs so they’d still fit into wizarding society (and avoid going to Azkaban if they could be seen as helping the Death Eaters). Lucius Malfoy, for example, likely would have still believed in pure-blood superiority, but he wouldn’t be able to advocate for it after the war, especially while trying to keep his status.

Comment: You might want to differentiate between pure-bloods and blood purists. The Weasleys were pure-bloods, after all.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Thanks a lot! :) I’ve added in some lines that hopefully make the distinction clearer.