# How are Ministers of Magic voted out by no-confidence?

Tags: harry-potter, ministry-of-magic

Do all the Heads of Departments come together and vote? Or does the Wizengamot vote? Or is it a public vote? Or is it a vote by the Lords of Houses, as in Lord Potter, Lord Malfoy etc?

I know that last one is not canon, ie, in the actual books, but I mean each family sends forth their Head or a representative and they vote.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15205/how-is-the-minister-for-magic-chosen-and-what-qualifications-are-required-to-hol

Comment: There are no "Lords of Houses" in the Potterverse

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15205/how-is-the-minister-for-magic-chosen-and-what-qualifications-are-required-to-hol, I don't see any mention of how the 'sacking' takes place other than the fact that their popularity matters

Comment: Indeed. And hence why I've posted it as a comment and not an answer or a dupe

Comment: Note that this question seems to contain an implicit assumption that there is an *external* mechanism (a vote) rather than an internal one, like a board ejecting its chairbeing, or a caucus revolt, or even an internal disciplinary procedure that can result in a criminal referral.

Comment: No, no. Isn't The Departmental Heads voting internal?